# Create view with multiple case without fonction

Tags: sql, oracle, view, case, ddl

Hello I have to make a view with oracle plsql but I dont know how can I done this wihtout create function:
I got this query
Hello I want to create view who use a query :

```
select unique  tv.id   , tv.homeid
case
    when ht.hometype = 'A7DF56ZEF' then 0 --HOUSE
    when ht.hometype = 'A7DF45ZEF'  then 1 -- SMALLHOUSE
end as housetype ,
case
    when tv.isfourk  is null then 0
    when tv.isfourk  is not null then 1
end as isfourk
from hometable ht
join tvtable tv on ht.idtv = tv.id
where tv.homeid = 'KLL5FD5Z6'
```

This query return me result like this

```
tv.id   tv.homeid  housetype    isfourk
A7844SD KLL5FD5Z6   1               0
A7944SD KLL5FD5Z6   1               0
A8044SD KLL5FD5Z6   1               0
```

I want to create a view using this query result. this query will be into the view.

The view will have only one row by  tv.homeid   , like this
Execpted result of the view:

```
TV.homeid     STATE
KLL5FD5Z6    (0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5)
```

STATE case condition

```
IF ALL ROWS HAVE isfourk = 1 THEN 1
ELSE IF ALL ROWS WHERE housetype = 1 HAVE isfourk = 1 THEN 2
ELSE IF ONE OF THESE ROWS HAVE isfourk = 0 THEN 3
ELSE IF ONE OF THESE ROWS WHERE housetype = 1 HAVE isfourk = 0 THEN 4
ELSE 5
END as STATE
```

If you can help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question, show the table definitions, sample data for both tables, and expected output from the view

Comment: I have edit with and expected ouptut

Comment: As I understood you have this query but it is not giving the result you desired and you want help there. Right ? I would keep view topic as second prio.

Comment: My query Give me a result, I want to use this query to create a view @Sujitmohanty30 how used this query

Comment: @MySqlDev788, But the query you put gives multiple rows but now based one this query you want to create a view which should apply the logic as you stated in CASE condition and provide one row per `homeid`. am I right ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

I have summarized the query as below after clarifications. I have used your query as base and on top of that applied the `case` logic to build the view.

One hint , use `DISTINCT` instead of `UNIQUE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW give_a_view_name
AS
SELECT homeid
      , CASE 
          WHEN MAX(isfourk) = 1 THEN 1 --IF ALL ROWS HAVE isfourk = 1
          WHEN MAX(isfourk) = 1 AND MAX(housetype) = 1 THEN 2 --IF ALL ROWS WHERE housetype = 1 HAVE isfourk = 1 THEN 2
          WHEN MIN(isfourk) = 0 THEN 3 --IF ONE OF THESE ROWS HAVE isfourk = 0 THEN 3
          WHEN MAX(housetype) = 1 AND MIN(isfourk) = 0 THEN 4 --IF ONE OF THESE ROWS WHERE housetype = 1 HAVE isfourk = 0 THEN 4
          ELSE 5 --ELSE 5
        END AS state
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
              tv.id
             ,tv.homeid
             ,CASE
               WHEN ht.hometype = 'A7DF56ZEF' THEN 0 --HOUSE
               WHEN ht.hometype = 'A7DF45ZEF' THEN 1 --SMALLHOUSE
              END AS housetype
             ,CASE 
               WHEN tv.isfourk IS NULL THEN 0
               WHEN tv.isfourk IS NOT NULL THEN 1
              END AS isfourk
          FROM   hometable ht
          JOIN   tvtable tv ON ht.idtv = tv.id
         WHERE  tv.homeid = 'KLL5FD5Z6')
GROUP BY homeid;
```

Check and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks , I thinks for the first case I need to set  MAX(isfourk) = 1 and  MIN(isfourk) = 1

Comment: @MySqlDev788, I think the base idea is to play with min and max and I did as you have mentioned the logic above but you can change accordingly anyway

Comment: @MySqlDev788, Did it solve your issue or the answer is not useful ?